# Laravel Customize authentication mechanism

Tags: laravel

I want to authenticate a user based upon the credentials which is in one database and date of birth which is in another database. I have searched for customization but what i just found is, customization using only one database and its table. Wasn't of much help to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the two databases manually and then [log in the user yourself](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods).

For example:

```
$user = User::where(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])->first();
$userSecondDb = UserSecondDb::where(['id' => $user->id, 'dateofbirth' => $dateofbirth])->first();
if (isset($user) && isset($userSecondDb))
{
    Auth::login($user);
}
```

Comment: I am a newbee to laravel, Auth::login($user) does it mean defining a function login in the Auth. And another question is after login i want to hide or display menu partial views based upon user privilege value. for example: if privilege = 3 display all and if privilege = 0 just display basic menu!!!!! @ Jerodev

Comment: And another thing do i need to do php artisan make:auth for this? I am not using it though. I am manually doing it. Please enlighten me!!!